# Mock a service of a service in another service Junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have the following service :

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    @Autowired
    protected ContractService contractService;

    private void saveInCache(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        this.contractService.saveInCache(multipartFile);
    }
}
```

and another service

```
@Service
public class ClientServiceImpl implements ClientService {

    @Autowired
    protected ContractService contractService;

    private void getInfoOfFile(String multipartFileId) {
        DocumentInfo document = this.contractService.getInfo(multipartFileId);
        ///
    }
}
```

and I have my Junit

```
public class ClientControllerTest extends ApiWebTest {

  @Mock
  protected ContractService contractService;

  @Autowired
  @InjectMocks
  protected ClientService clientService = new ClientServiceImpl();

  @Before
  private void setup() {
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  private void testGetInfo() {
     // Code
     DocumentInfo multipartFile = new DocumentInfo();
     multipartFile.setMultipartFileId(1234);
     when(this.contractService.getInfo(multipartFile.getMultipartFileId())).thenReturn(multipartFile);

   // Test the Client service 'getInfoOfFile' method.
  }
}
```

When i run this test in debug mode, I see that the `this.contractService.getInfo(multipartFileId);` is returning me 'null'.

Where am I going wrong in mocking.

I have just mocked the ContractService in my JUnit. Do I need to mock even the AccountServiceImpl as well ?

EDIT : Adding the saveInCache and getInfo methods

```
private DocumentInfo getInfo(String documentId) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(documentId)) {
            return null;
        }
        WriteLock lock = this.readWriteLock.writeLock();
        try {
            lock.lock();
            DocumentInfo cachedDocument = this.documentCache.get(documentId);
            return cachedDocument;
        } finally {
            if (lock != null) {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

private DocumentInfo saveInCache(StreamingStorage document) {
        if (document == null) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Creative document is required to put into cache.");
        }
        WriteLock lock = this.readWriteLock.writeLock();
        try {
            lock.lock();
            DocumentInfo newCachedDocument = this.documentCache.put(document.getDocumentId(), document);
            return newCachedDocument;
        } finally {
            if (lock != null) {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You dont need @Autowired for protected ClientService clientService; Also instead of protected ClientService clientService; try with - private ClientServiceImpl clientService

Comment: Also getInfo of ContractService is not visible. Could you please add that method?

Comment: @asg Added the methods

Comment: This entire process will be much simpler, and you can eliminate Spring entirely, if you use constructor injection in your services.

Comment: Isn't there a compilation issue in your Test class as you are telling Mockito to expect `DocumentInfo` object for `getInfo()` method, but actually it accepts `String`? In this line of code `when(this.contractService.getInfo(multipartFile)).thenReturn(multipartFile)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It was a typo !

Comment: Can you post your exact test method. Seems like there is something missing.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're contradicting yourself with the declaration of the clientService.

You have:

```
@Autowired
@InjectMocks
protected ClientService clientService = new ClientServiceImpl();
```

This should create an autowired ClientService called clientService and inject the mocks.  However the `= new ClientServiceImpl()` will then override the autowiring and create you a plain vanilla one (I think!).  Also `@Autowired` and `@InjectMocks` are also not needed at the same time - you want to create a service with mocks injected - not an autowired object.

can you try changing you test like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClientControllerTest extends ApiWebTest {

  @Mock
  protected ContractService contractService;

  @InjectMocks
  protected ClientService clientService;

  @Test
  private void testGetInfo() {
     DocumentInfo multipartFile = new DocumentInfo();
     multipartFile.setMultipartFileId(1234);
     when(this.contractService.getInfo(multipartFile)).thenReturn(multipartFile);

  }
}
```

Adding `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` means all the object creation happens without the need for any further work from you.

Comment: Tried with that earlier. Still no luck !

Comment: I've added a bigger example: remove the Autowired, and added a Runwith.  This works for me

Answer (score 2):

[@InjectMocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) creates an instance of the class and injects the mocks that are created with the `@Mock` annotations into it. So you don't have to create the instance of ClientService, and remove `@Autowired` on it.

You can use [MockitoJUnitRunner](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.8/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) instead of `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`. The code is simpler.

Testclass after changes:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClientControllerTest extends ApiWebTest {

    @Mock
    private ContractService contractService;

    @InjectMocks
    private ClientService clientService;

    @Test
    private void testGetInfo() {
       // Code
       DocumentInfo multipartFile = new DocumentInfo();
       multipartFile.setMultipartFileId(1234);

       when(this.contractService.getInfo(multipartFile)).thenReturn(multipartFile);

       // Test the Client service 'getInfoOfFile' method.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     DocumentInfo multipartFile = new DocumentInfo();
     multipartFile.setMultipartFileId(1234);
     when(this.contractService.getInfo(multipartFile)).thenReturn(multipartFile);
```

Here you expect `multipartFile` instance in your mock which is not the case since since there will be another instance of `DocumentInfo` during the test (see `getInfo` method which creates it).

You should change your mock to be something like this:

```
 when(this.contractService.getInfo(any())).thenReturn(multipartFile);
```

In this case, the expectation will be matched against any instance of DocumentInfo instead of your particular instance that you create via constructor `multipartFile = new DocumentInfo();`

Answer (score 1):

Root cause: You didn't inject the ContractService into the ClientService.

I think you can solve the problem much easier by using **ReflectionTestUtils**. It means you will inject the mocked ContractService to the AccountServiceImpl.

```
public class ClientControllerTest extends ApiWebTest {
  protected ClientService clientService = new ClientServiceImpl();
  private ContractService contractService;
  @Test
  private void testGetInfo() 
  {
     // Code
     DocumentInfo multipartFile = new DocumentInfo();
     multipartFile.setMultipartFileId(1234);
     contractService= EasyMock.createNiceMock(ContractService.class);
     ReflectionTestUtils.setField(clientService, "contractService", contractService);
     EasyMock.expect(contractService.getInfo(multipartFile.getMultipartFileId())).andReturn(multipartFile).anyTimes();
     EasyMock.replay(contractService);
  }
}
```

You can apply the same for JUnit